# What type of C++ cast should be used to cast a pointer to a struct to its first member?

Tags: c++, struct, casting

`X` is defined as the following:

```
struct X
{
    Y y;
    // more fields...
    int a;
};
```

I have a variable of type `X`. However, I would like to cast it to the type of its first member, in order to pass that into a function. I know that the C Standard permits it (and I suppose the C++ one does so as well).

In C I would do it like so:

```
X x;
Y* y = (Y*) x;
doStuff(y);
```

What type of cast is the right one in C++ for this? `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: `static_cast` doesn't compile for this

Comment: *as the standard permits* The standard does not permit this.

Comment: @FredLarson In this case, I have a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` variable. However the WinAPI function `GetProcessMemoryInfo` takes a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*`. The former type starts with the exact same fields as the latter, and adds a few at the end. The intended usage is to pass into the function a pointer to the latter type, even if we hold a pointer to the former (larger) type.

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right, I meant to say something a bit different. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @FredLarson: The linux kernel uses something like this (in C, obviously) to handle a lot of the driver structures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-the-linux-kernel.

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698298/getprocessmemoryinfo-process-memory-counters-ex-privateusage-always-0)?

Comment: @NathanOliver how about pointer interconvertibility between a pointer to the structure and a pointer to its first element?

Comment: @Fureeish Yep that's what I meant. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Fureeish They might be okay with that, but that caveat only applies to standard layout classes.  Not sure if `// more fields...` leaves `Y` as standard layout or not.

Comment: @AvivCohn I think your question doesn't quite express what you want to do. All you would need to do to do the "equivalent" of your C code is `doStuff(&x.y)`, which I'm pretty sure you would have done if that was a possibility for you.

Comment: Unrelated Typo: `Y* y = (Y*) x;` -> `Y* y = (Y*) &x;`

Comment: `doStuff(&x.y);` looks to be more suitable than anything else you could do here. Better example required?

Comment: Why not use the address of the first element, if that's what you're trying to do. This is very strange & dangerous.

Comment: Used to do this all the time C. For example, if you put the linked list node structure as the first member of another struct, you have a sort-of poor-man's polymporphism. The casting is usually done on the way out, though. Can blow up in your face very badly in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd always recommend using `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast` in any situation where the `static_cast` isn't rejected by the compiler. If possible try to avoid doing any casting at all - in this case you probably want: `Y* y = &x.y`.

To answer the comment:

> In this case, I have a PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX
> variable. However the WinAPI function GetProcessMemoryInfo takes a
> PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*. The former type starts with the exact same
> fields as the latter, and adds a few at the end. The intended usage is
> to pass into the function a pointer to the latter type, even if we
> hold a pointer to the former (larger) type.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo) for GetProcessMemoryInfo() states that the second parameter is:

> A pointer to the PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS or PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX
> structure that receives information about the memory usage of the
> process.

The Win32 API is a C API, and not a C++ one, so you can just use a C style cast here, or preferably a `reinterpret_cast` to make your intention clearer. I'd expect `static_cast` to be rejected by the compiler in this case. Note that the third `cb` parameter is there to tell the function which type of structure you actually provided - it should be set to either `sizeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS)` or `sizeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX)`.

Answer (score 4):

None.

You can't mess around with objects using pointers like that. C++ is not C, and these are not "just bytes" (contrary to popular belief).

And you don't need to!

Pass `&x.y` instead; it's already the `Y*` you want.

Comment: Apart from the obvious typo, `reinterpret_cast` is most likely the correct cast. It's not none.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Since this original question was not properly phrased, I opened a new one more accurately explains the question. Essentially, the question should have been written to say simply that `Y` starts with the exact same layout as `X`. But it does not contain an `X` directly. Please see updated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196623/what-is-the-correct-way-to-cast-a-struct-to-a-type-that-matches-its-first-set-of

Answer (score 0):

> @FredLarson In this case, I have a PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX variable. However the WinAPI function GetProcessMemoryInfo takes a PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*. **The former type starts with the exact same fields as the latter**, and adds a few at the end. The intended usage is to pass into the function a pointer to the latter type, even if we hold a pointer to the former (larger) type.

The cleanest way to accomplish that would be probably (ab)using inheritance. This way, you can have your `_EX` type share members with the base type while actually being an instance of it.

```
struct X {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct X_EX : public X {
  int other_member;
};

void doStuff(X*);

void foo(X_EX* ptr) {
 doStuff(ptr);
}
```

However, do note that "Inherit-to-extend" is seen as a code smell, and something to avoid if possible nowadays. I'd make sure to put a comment explaining why it's necessary here.