# What is the correct way to cast a struct to a type that matches its first set of members?

Tags: c++, struct, casting

Please consider the following structs from the WinAPI:

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS {
  DWORD  cb;
  DWORD  PageFaultCount;
  SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
} PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;

typedef struct _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX {
  DWORD  cb;
  DWORD  PageFaultCount;
  SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PrivateUsage;
} PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX;
```

As you can see, `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` "inherits from" `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` - the former starts with the exact definition of the latter, and adds an additional field.

Consider a function:

```
BOOL GetProcessMemoryInfo(
  HANDLE                   Process,
  PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS ppsmemCounters,
  DWORD                    cb
);
```

As you can see, it takes a `PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`. However I would like to pass it a pointer to a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX`.

According to the standard, correct me if I'm wrong, I should be able to cast a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX*` to a `PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*`, since the former starts with the exact definition of the latter.

In C it would be done like so:

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
GetProcessMemoryInfo(process, (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*) &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
```

What is the correct way to do this in C++ code, if any? Should I use `reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmc)`, `static_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmc)`, or something else?

Comment: Well static_cast won't compile, so you should use reinterpret_cast.

Comment: why does `B` not actually inherit from `A` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 As I explained, since I'm using a C API which expects specific C structs to be passed in. I'm just wondering how to do this cast in proper C++, against this C API.

Comment: but `A` is a plain struct and if `B` inherts from it then getting a `A*` from a `B*` can be done

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I have no control over these struct definitions. They are defined by WinAPI.

Comment: @AvivCohn What are the real WinAPI structs? What is the real function you want to call with a `B*` that is expecting an `A*`?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, You should post real structs involved. If they are from WinAPI then docs probably describe the way they are supposed to be used.

Comment: Use a real example then.  I've never seen `struct A` and `struct B` in the WinAPI.

Comment: @paddy Please see the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation states that `GetProcessMemoryInfo` accepts

> A pointer to the PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS or PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX structure that receives information about the memory usage of the process.

So, `reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmc)` would be the answer to your question.

But you must set `cb` to the size of object being passed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The signature of the function technically takes a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*`, so the question is how I properly cast an `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX*` to one in C++. A C style cast is an option of course, but I'm wondering what kind of C++ cast is the most appropriate.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmc)` would be the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Great, if you post an answer I'll accept :) A bit of elaboration as to the reason why `static_cast` is not the right choice would also be welcome. Thanks

Comment: @AvivCohn i would use `static_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *>(static_cast<void *>(::std::addressof(counters))) ` (i actually use a special pointer_cast routine for situations like this)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Accessing the object through the converted pointer would violate pointer aliasing rules.

Comment: @eerorika It won't because implementation will cast it back to PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX according to `cb` value

Comment: @eerorika I _think_ it's ok when dealing with the WinAPI. I could be wrong but this is very common in it.

Comment: @user7860670 Ah. If it's casted back, then it's fine.

Comment: @user7860670 The static cast through `void*` is pointless since it is exactly same as reinterpret_cast by definition. `::std::addressof` can be useful if you cannot trust that the operator isn't overloaded for the class.

Comment: @eerorika dual static_cast instead of reinterpret_cast here is a way to separate pointer conversions from conversions of different kinds of entities (integer <-> pointer). `addressof` is useful unless you want to call overloaded operator & because it makes it possible to distinguish reference declaration, bit_and operation from actually taking an address (basically working search). imho `addressof` should've been a built-in operator similar to & with no support for overloading.

Comment: @user7860670 There are no integers involved in this cast, but if there were, there would be no difference in the result between the static casts through `void*` and reinterpret cast.

Comment: @eerorika yes, but using pointer_cast for pointer conversions and reinterpret_cast for other conversions makes intents clearer

Answer (score 1):

> According to the standard, correct me if I'm wrong, I should be able to cast a B* to a A*

Cast, yes. This would be a `reinterpret_cast`. But depending on how the pointer is going to be used, it might not be practical. In particular, you couldn't access `B` through the pointer to `A`.

Casting the pointer back is one thing that can be done, so this would be well-defined:

```
void f(A* a) {
    B* b = reinterpret_cast<B*>(a);
    // ...
}

extern b* b;
f(reinterpret_cast<A*>(b));
```

Another thing that can be done with the reinterpreted pointer is to reinterpret it again as pointer to char and for example `memcpy` or `memcmp` the memory.

---

If you do need to access the "common initial sequence", then you could change the function. Because accessing common initial sequence of inactive standard layout struct member is an allowed special case of unions, this would work:

```
union AB {
    A a;
    B b;
};

void f(AB& ab) {
    // can access all members of ab.a
    // regardless of which member is active
} 

AB ab {
    .b = {},
};
f(ab);
```

Answer (score 1):

As types are unrelated by inheritance rules, and none of them is void, you should use `reinterpret_cast`.

As explained by @[eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196731/3545273), it will indeed be a violation of the non aliasing rule.

It will work anyway, with common compilers (and specifically with MSVC) because the types are trivially copyable. This would be perfectly legal:

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX a = ...;  // initialized a object
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS b;           // uninitialized b object;

memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));           // copy the REPRESENTATION
```

The representation is just a series of bytes so it is legal to copy it. The beginning of the representation of `a` is a valid representation for `b`, so you get a valid `b` object.

This is an intended usage for `reinterpret_cast`. We know that this does happen when dealing with legacy code, of when mixing C and C++ functions. So `reinterpret_cast` allow to use the representation of an object *as if* is was the representation of a different object. It cannot be anything other than UB on a standard point of view, because the representations of types are willingly not defined by the standard beyond some trivial cases.

But if you know that it will used on a specific architecture with a specific set of compilers, it will work.

Comment: It will work because implementation will figure out correct type using `cb` argument and cast the pointer passed back to `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` (and fill extra fields in it). It is just one of old functions with fixed signature accepting pointers to different objects through a pointer with fixed type.